# KivyMD Remove a Expansion Panel

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm having trouble finding the solution in how to remove an expansion panel which inside of it it contains TwoLineAvatarListItem with a IconLeftWidget, and below that is a MDCard with two MDlabels for text. I've tried to use self.root.ids.remove_widget() but it does not do anything. I've tried many ways and have not found the solution. Here is the code please feel free to view. Thanks

kv. file

```
<Content>:
    adaptive_height: True
    #size_hint: 1, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TwoLineAvatarListItem:
        text: "Message"
        secondary_text: 'to: @gmail.com'
        IconLeftWidget:
            icon: 'email'


    MDCard:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: "8dp"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "280dp", "180dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

        MDLabel:
            text: "Title"
            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]


        MDSeparator:
            height: "1dp"

        MDLabel:
            text: "Body"

ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        id: messages
        name: 'messages'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: "Messages Center"
                elevation:8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: 'arrow-left'
                    on_press: screen_manager.current = "main_app_screen"
                    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 1
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    id: box
```

.py python file

```
class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(10):
            panel = MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon=f"{images_path}folder.png",
                     content=Content(),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                        text='',
                        secondary_text=str(i) + ' email: xxxxx@gmail.com',))

            self.root.ids.box.add_widget(panel)

DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Content>:
    [...]


    MDCard:
        [...]

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "REMOVE"
            on_release: app.remove(root)

        [...]



class DemoApp(MDApp):
    [...]

    def remove(self, content):
        self.root.ids.box.remove_widget(content.parent)
```

Comment: Xyanight thank you. I was able to implement the button and remove a widget. Cheers!